# как построчно считывать ответ команды?

Tags: python

допустим есть питон скрипт, при запуске которого он рандомным образом отправляет по 2-3 команды в консоль, с промежутком времени 5-10 секунд
мне нужно с другого питон скрипта каждый раз получать новые 2-3 команды и считывать их

накидал пример кода чтоб меня было проще понять:

python_script.py:

```
from time import sleep
import random
while True:
    cl = random.randint(2,3)
    slp = random.randint(5,10)
    sleep(slp)
    while cl > 0:
        cl = cl - 1
        print("hello world")
```

файл который должен его считывать:

```
while True:
    os.system("cd Desktop && python3 python_script.py")
    #и тут должен быть код который будет построчно считывать ответ
```

Comment: А почему не сделать проще через запись и считывание в файл?

Comment: @Сергей, я бы вообще предложил в sqlite с последующим добавлением отметки о времени и результатах выполнения...

Comment: может скрипт, отправщик будет слать и в консоль и в куданадо ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, не верна концепция.
Я бы сделал что-то такое...
Если условно взять написанный ниже код за генератор строк `python_script.py`:

```py
import time

def line_gen():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield count
        time.sleep(1)
```

То (при условии нахождения этого генератора непонятно где на диске):

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'path/to/folder/with/python_script.py')
from python_script import line_gen

for item in line_gen():
    print(item)
```

> Но что-то мне подсказывает, что если автор более подробно расскажет о своей задаче, то ему порекомендуют создать сокет

Comment: создать сокет нет возможности, ибо файл python_script.py вообще не мой, и там код +- на 15к строк

Comment: хотя похоже вы правы, сделать сокет будет правильней и проще всего, пусть и прийдеться переделывать много кода